# Magento shows 404 error page on a product on one PC

Tags: product, magento-enterprise, 404-page

This is a weird problem. We have an item on the test server showing a 404 error page when you put in the URL key after the root URL (eg. www.mystore.com/url_key), however on our local machines they don't do this. I've even restored my local database so it's identical to the test server and it's not getting a 404.

The URL rewrites are identical, both my local machine and the test server has full page cache on.

Now, we could fix it by reindexing but we want to know the cause as to why the test server is showing a 404 while a local WAMP server doesn't.

Comment: Set some breakpoints or`die()` statements to help provide more information to debug (e.g. "Can get to the controller, but breaks on line X")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One explanation is your .htaccess isn't being picked up. Can you try to add in index.php in the URL and see if this solves the issue?

```
index.php/url_key
```

Comment: yep, that worked, so the problem could very well be the .htaccess file, i'll check it out

Answer (score 3):

How did you sync the two databases? MySQL import and export?

If you just copied the database over you have to clear the cache, because that is stored on the filesystem and has still data cached from the old database.
Reindex wouldn't help in that case, because the index is also stored in the MySQL database.

Comment: yeh i do a import and export however while yes the cache could be to blame and clearing it would fix it, the only why i could see this to have happened if someone went into the item when it didn't exist which is next to impossible cause someone would have to have guessed the url key and when we check items with Test Scripts, we have the script act as a user so the item has to appear in the catalog view before we can go into it (we dont insert the URLs for testing)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your DB and run this query:

```
INSERT INTO `report_event_types` (`event_type_id`, `event_name`, `customer_login`) VALUES
(1, 'catalog_product_view', 1),
(2, 'sendfriend_product', 1),
(3, 'catalog_product_compare_add_product', 1),
(4, 'checkout_cart_add_product', 1),
(5, 'wishlist_add_product', 1),
(6, 'wishlist_share', 1);
```

P.S. check DB name prefix if you have it!